# How to testfor a specific score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any possible way to testfor a specific deathCount score?

As of right now I am using:

```
/testfor @p[score_Deaths_min=1]
```

Is there a way to make it specific? Like:

```
/testfor @p[score_Deaths=1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. `@p[score_Deaths_min=1,score_Deaths=1]` will select the nearest player with precisely one death. What this means is that the *minimum* score `Deaths` can be is `1`, and the *maximum* (denoted with no specific symbol) score `Deaths` can be is also 1. Hence, the only score that is true for that command `1`. So the command becomes `/testfor @p[score_Deaths_min=1,score_Deaths=1]`.

Comment: @JP2K If that answer helped you, please consider marking it as correct.